# Is DataNucleus working in JBoss Java EE app server for JPA access to LDAP DB?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, ldap, datanucleus

I would like to access an LDAP database (and maybe NoSQL db in the future) using JBoss Java EE app server. I would like to keep standard JPA annotations and not using direct LDAP APIs in my EJBs if possible.

Has anyone got some successful experience in deploying JBoss app server with DataNucleus for the JPA mapping on LDAP protocol? AFAIK, Hibernate is not able to handle this.

Thanks !

Comment: The DataNucleus store plugin being used ought to be irrelevant  to  use in a JEE server; could be RDBMS, LDAP, Excel, MongoDB or whatever. Recent DN releases have all been deployed in JBoss 4/5, and current SVN also supports JBoss 6. You don't say what happens when you try

Comment: Thanks DataNucleus. I did not try yet, I just want to get feedback on people's experience in doing this. I'm glad to here it is supported. I will certainly give it a try.